# Django csrf forbidden on url variation

Tags: django, internationalization, csrf

Hi I have an html template for switching languages on my site:

```
<form action="{{ SITE_URL }}i18n/setlang/" name="postlink" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <ul class="lang">
        <li class="lang">
            {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
                {% if lang.0 != LANGUAGE_CODE %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="language" value="{{ lang.0 }}">
                    <a class="active" href=# onclick="submitPostLink()">{{ lang.1 }}</a>
                {% else %}
                    {{ lang.1 }}
                {% endif %}
                {% if forloop.last %}{% else %} &nbsp; | &nbsp;{% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

All this works fine on the dev server and in production and in production at the normal url of **www.mysite.com/project/**

However, if I try  **project.mysite.com** or **mysite.com.project** I get my home page as normal but changing the language brings up the 403 Forbidden failure.

Do I need to define the root url variations I need for `setlang` somewhere?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since these urls are running on different subdomains, you should check the domain setting for the CSRF cookie `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/csrf/#subdomains

Comment: Just found that. Can I add multiple subdomains to this setting?

Comment: As noted in the docs you can enable this for all subdomains by using `.mysite.com`.

Comment: Actually - it solved the forbidden error message but now when I switch languages the page just reloads with the same language. Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe the chosen language is also stored in a cookie so it is probably a similar problem and solution.

Comment: hmmm. Any hints on what that solution might be?

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar enough with Django's internationalization. You'd probably have better luck asking it as another question.